# Is there a node class, such as NSNode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a node class, such as NSNode or similar in objective-c, or should I roll my own?  Searching doesn't seem to turn up anything.

Something simple with add/remove nodes/children, etc.

Comment: Probably NSMutableArray would be the closest.

Comment: Would this hypothetical `NSNode` class represent Internet hosts? Vertices in a graph? Points in a waveform? Orbital nodes?

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I was thinking of something similar to Cocos2d's CCNode's, that are purely for storing any other 'CCNode' object.  NSMutableArray is close, but not quite.  Wasn't sure if there was already something like this available or not.

Comment: CCArray is close.  It may be worth forking it and customizing the code.  So I'm guessing the answer is 'no,' there isn't a NSNode class ?

Comment: Not for use in a Cocos2d project  =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`CFTree`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html). It does not have a corresponding `NS` wrapper, but it provides the operations that you are looking for: adding other `CFTree` instances as children, iterating over siblings, associating your own data with a tree node, and so on. Becoming comfortable with Core Foundation programming takes some time, but it is usually better than rolling your own.

Comment: You could also probably write a decent Objective-C wrapper around CFTree if an interface that's more Foundation-like is important to you...

Comment: Not familiar enough with Foundation to do that, but CFTree is closest to what I was looking for.  Too bad there isn't an NS wrapper for it.  I've decided to fork CCArray and customize it for my needs.  This answer was closest!

Comment: It's certainly understandable if your schedule and/or the requirements of the project don't allow you time to do so, but being able to effectively use Core Foundation stuff can be quite valuable, and isn't really that hard.

Answer (score 0):

[This Objective-C Node class](https://github.com/cxx6xxc/Node) allows intuitive access to nodes via the *Unix path convention* or array index convention, whereas CFTree only allows access by via array index convention.  The benefit of a using the Unix path convention allows human readable naming of nodes which acts much like a dictionary key access of nodes via path names.

Node also has symbolic links, which give you the ability to create nodes that point to node branches deep within the node structure.  Links may have nodes created, copied, renamed, moved and deleted through them.

Here is an example of the Node class primitive methods:

```
- (id)initRoot

- (id)makeNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath

- (void)deleteNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath

- (void)copyNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath toPath:(NSString*)toPath

- (void)moveNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath toPath:(NSString*)toPath

- (void)renameNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath toPath:(NSString*)toPath

- (void)linkNodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath toPath:(NSString*)toPath

- (id)nodeAtPath:(NSString*)atPath

- (NSString*)path

- (NSMutableArray*)allNodes
```